# RDP client error using Cisco SSL VPN

Tags: ubuntu, windows-7, ssl, rdp, cisco-vpn

I am using a Cisco SSL VPN client to connect from a 32-bit Ubuntu 11.04 computer to a 32-bit Windows 7 computer. When I request an RDP session from the SSL VPN site, the properJavaRDP plugin fires up, makes a connection to the server, and then returns the following error:

```
Connection Exception Wrong Modulus size! Expected64+8got:264
```

My session can never get past that point. Has anyone seen this error before and have any clue how to resolve it?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some more information that might be helpful,

[Cisco ASA - Java RDP Error - Connection Exception Wrong modulus size](http://www.petenetlive.com/KB/Article/0000452.htm)

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault, Pete. We advise against answers here that purely link off-site. Please consider pasting the relevant information into your answer here - that way, if the site you linked to ever goes down the solution is not lost. Also, please give our [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq) the once over, especially the **Can I use a signature or tagline?** section.

Answer (score 0):

The properJavaRDP plugin will not work with Windows 7.  The Cisco rdp2 plugin needs to be installed on the ASA.